# PicketLink integration with TomEE

Tags: apache-tomee, picketlink, tomee-7

I'm trying to integrate PicketLink for the security needs of a JEE 7 webapp I'm developing with TomEE 7.0.1. I've implemented the basic example from PicketLink site. However, PicketLink is failing to authenticate the form input and logs "Account NOT FOUND for credentials ...". Here's my implementation:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    public void onInit(@Observes org.picketlink.event.SecurityConfigurationEvent event) {
        org.picketlink.config.SecurityConfigurationBuilder builder = event.getBuilder();

        builder
            .http()
                .allPaths()
                    .authenticateWith()
                        .form()
                            .authenticationUri("/login.xhtml")
                            .loginPage("/") // Invokes a servlet which forwards to login.xhtml
                            .errorPage("/")
                            .redirectTo("/index.xhtml")
//                            .restoreOriginalRequest()
                .forPath("/javax.faces.resource/*")
                    .unprotected()
                .forPath("/logout")
                    .logout()
                    .redirectTo("/")
                .forPath("/register.xhtml")
                    .unprotected();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Startup
public class SecurityInitializer {
    @Inject
    private PartitionManager partitionManager;

    //@Inject
    //private IdentityManager identityManager; // This didn't work either

    @PostConstruct
    public void create() {
        IdentityManager identityManager = this.partitionManager.createIdentityManager();

        User user = new User("jane");

        user.setEmail("jane@doe.com");
        user.setFirstName("Jane");
        user.setLastName("Doe");

        identityManager.add(user);
        identityManager.updateCredential(user, new Password("1234"));
    }
}
```

login.xhtml

```
<body id="loginform">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="login"> 
            <h:form prependId="false">
                <h:inputText id="j_username" value="#{loginCredentials.userId}" required="true" pt:placeholder="Username" />
                <h:inputSecret id="j_password" value="#{loginCredentials.password}" required="true" pt:placeholder="Password" />
                <h:commandButton value="Sign In" action="#{identity.login}"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </body>
```

The log output:

```
Performing authentication using credentials [org.picketlink.idm.credential.Password@55f9cac7]. User id is [jane].
10:17:09.161 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Firing event [org.picketlink.authentication.event.PreAuthenticateEvent@164f832e].
10:17:09.163 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.authentication - Authentication is going to be performed by authenticator [org.picketlink.authentication.internal.IdmAuthenticator@3a946b61]
10:17:09.163 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.authentication - Validating credentials [org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@5028d9ee] using PicketLink IDM.
10:17:09.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Initializing Identity Management Subsystem.
10:17:09.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Creating PartitionManager.
10:17:09.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Building identity management configuration.
10:17:09.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - IdentityConfiguration not provided by the application, creating a default IdentityConfigurationBuilder.
10:17:09.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Firing event [org.picketlink.IdentityConfigurationEvent@465bebd2].
10:17:09.176 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - No configuration provided by the application. Configuring defaults.
10:17:09.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.common - Using logger implementation: org.picketlink.common.DefaultPicketLinkLogger
10:17:09.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Auto configuring File Identity Store.
10:17:09.191 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  org.picketlink.idm - PLIDM001000: Bootstrapping PicketLink IDM Partition Manager
10:17:09.196 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -   Identity Management Configuration: [
10:17:09.196 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Name: default
10:17:09.196 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Identity Store Configuration: [org.picketlink.idm.config.FileIdentityStoreConfiguration@f1f99fd]
10:17:09.196 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Supports Partition: true
10:17:09.196 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Supports Attribute: true
10:17:09.196 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Supports Credential: true
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Supports Permission: true
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -     Supported Types: [interface org.picketlink.idm.model.IdentityType, interface org.picketlink.idm.model.Relationship, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.GroupMembership, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Agent, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Group, interface org.picketlink.idm.model.Partition, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.GroupRole, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Realm, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Grant, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Role]
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm -   ]
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  org.picketlink.idm.identity.store - PLIDM001001: Initializing Identity Store [class org.picketlink.idm.file.internal.FileIdentityStore]
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store - [org.picketlink.idm.config.FileIdentityStoreConfiguration@f1f99fd]: [
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Type: class org.picketlink.idm.file.internal.FileIdentityStore
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Supports partition: true
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Supports attribute: true
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Supports credential: true
10:17:09.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Credential Handlers: [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.PasswordCredentialHandler, class org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.X509CertificateCredentialHandler, class org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.DigestCredentialHandler, class org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.TOTPCredentialHandler, class org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.TokenCredentialHandler]
10:17:09.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Supported types: [interface org.picketlink.idm.model.IdentityType, interface org.picketlink.idm.model.Relationship, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.GroupMembership, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Agent, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Group, interface org.picketlink.idm.model.Partition, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.GroupRole, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Realm, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Grant, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User, class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Role]
10:17:09.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Unsupported types: []
10:17:09.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store -   Context Initializers: [org.picketlink.internal.AuthenticatedAccountContextInitializer@1a402a5]
10:17:09.256 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.identity.store - ]
10:17:09.276 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - PLIDM001101: Working directory [C:\Everything Mine\bin\TomEE\apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1\temp\pl-idm] is marked to be always created. All your existing data will be lost.
10:17:09.328 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - PLIDM001100: Using working directory [C:\Everything Mine\bin\TomEE\apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1\temp\pl-idm].
10:17:09.331 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - No partitions to load from C:\Everything Mine\bin\TomEE\apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1\temp\pl-idm\pl-idm-partitions.db
10:17:09.333 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Firing event [org.picketlink.PartitionManagerCreateEvent@27bddd38].
10:17:09.336 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Creating default partition using [class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Realm] and name [default].
10:17:09.343 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - Initializing Partition [default] with id [f1dec0b1-f9b2-4f34-b638-2d174dd5a475].
10:17:09.346 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - Loaded Identity Types [0] for Partition [f1dec0b1-f9b2-4f34-b638-2d174dd5a475].
10:17:09.348 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - Loaded Credentials [0] for Partition [f1dec0b1-f9b2-4f34-b638-2d174dd5a475].
10:17:09.351 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.picketlink.idm.identity.store.file - Loaded Permissions [0] for Partition [f1dec0b1-f9b2-4f34-b638-2d174dd5a475].
10:17:09.378 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Firing event [org.picketlink.idm.event.PartitionCreatedEvent@6313ddb9].
10:17:09.381 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.credential - Starting validation for credentials [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials][org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@5028d9ee] using identity store [org.picketlink.idm.file.internal.FileIdentityStore@20439b63] and credential handler [org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.PasswordCredentialHandler@35ecbf5c].
10:17:09.383 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.credential - PLIDM001003: Trying to find account [jane] using default account type [class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Agent] with property [loginName].
10:17:09.383 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.credential - PLIDM001003: Trying to find account [jane] using default account type [class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User] with property [loginName].
10:17:09.383 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.credential - Account NOT FOUND for credentials [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials][org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@5028d9ee].
10:17:09.383 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.idm.credential - Finishing validation for credential [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials][org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@5028d9ee] validated using identity store [org.picketlink.idm.file.internal.FileIdentityStore@20439b63] and credential handler [org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.PasswordCredentialHandler@35ecbf5c]. Status [INVALID]. Validated Account [null]
10:17:09.383 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.authentication - Credential status is [INVALID] and validated account [null]
10:17:09.386 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  org.picketlink.authentication - PLINK002100: Authentication failed for account [jane].
10:17:09.386 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink - Firing event [org.picketlink.authentication.event.LoginFailedEvent@13834ca3].
10:17:09.386 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.picketlink.authentication - Authentication is finished using credentials [org.picketlink.idm.credential.Password@55f9cac7]. User id is [jane].
```

I'm unable to find any helpful documents to help me start off. Does anybody of you have any experience with integrating the two of these. What do I need to do to integrate PicketLink with TomEE based JSF app ? Alternatively, I also looked at KeyCloak but that too does not have any pointers on integrating with TomEE.

Answer (score 0):

picketlink-authentication-form-with-jsf example provided by picketlink runs on tomee.

Here are the needed dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
  <artifactId>picketlink-api</artifactId>
  <version>${version.picketlink}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
  <artifactId>picketlink-impl</artifactId>
  <version>${version.picketlink}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

(don't forget jboss-logging which doesn't come transitively)

To run the example you also need javaee-api and myfaces-api to get EE dependencies but these two should be in scope provided.